# Custom UserProvider config symfony 4

Tags: symfony, ldap, php-7.3, symfony-4.3

I would like to create my own LdapUserProvider to apply different role regarding the username.
Accutally my LDAP works really good with the default LdapUserProvider from symfony.

As the [LDAP doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html#ldap-configuration-reference) say :

*The ldap user provider, using the LdapUserProvider class. Like all other user providers, it can be used with any authentication provider.*

How can I do to use a customized User provider please?

```
security:
        providers:
            my_ldap:
                ldap:
                    service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                    base_dn: o=xxx
                    search_dn: cn=xxx Downloader,ou=ApplicationUsers,o=xxx
                    search_password: 'xxx'
                    default_roles: [ROLE_USER]
                    uid_key: uid
                    filter: "{uid_key}={username}"

        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
            main:
                anonymous: true
    #            provider: App\Services\MyLdapUserProvider
                logout:
                    csrf_token_id: logout
                    path: /logout
                    target: /login
                form_login_ldap:
                    csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                    login_path: login
                    check_path: login
                    service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                    dn_string: 'o=xxx'
                    query_string: 'uid={username}'
                    target_path_parameter: home
                    default_target_path:  /home

        access_control:
            - { path: /index, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
            - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**Edit:**
Thank you for your answer @Vyctorya

I think this is what I need!

In security.yaml this is how I call the service:

```
security:
        providers:
            myLdap:
                id: App\Services\MyLdapUserProvider
```

and this is my service.yaml:

```
services:
        App\Services\MyLdapUserProvider:
            arguments:
                $ldap: '@Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapInterface'
                $baseDn: 'o=xxx'
                $searchDn: 'cn=xxx Downloader,ou=ApplicationUsers,o=xxx'
                $searchPassword: 'xxx'
                $defaultRoles:
                    'ROLE_USER'
                $uidKey: 'uid'
                $filter: '{uid_key}={username}'

        Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapInterface:
            arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']

        Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
            arguments:
                - host: ....
```

I don't uderstand why baseDn is not defined...

*Cannot autowire service "App\Services\MyLdapUserProvider": argument "$baseDn" of method "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider::__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-provider).

You need to adjust your configuration:

```
security:
    providers:
        enter_you_custom_name_here:
            id: AppBundle\Security\User\UserProvider
```

and create the `UserProvider`. Extend `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider` and override `loadUserByUsername($username)`